# Exercise 7.1.6 Introduction to Set Theory by Hrbacek and Jech

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

This is exercise 7.1.6 of the book *Introduction to Set Theory* 3rd ed. by Hrbacek and Jech.

> Let $h^{*}(A)$ be the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that there exists no function with domain $A$ and range $\alpha$. Prove:
>
> (a) If $\alpha \geq h^{*}(A) $, then there is no function with domain $A$ and range $\alpha$.
>
> (b) $h^{*}(A)$ is an initial ordinal.
>
> (c) $h(A)\leq h^*(A)$ ($h(A)$ denotes the Hartogs's number of $A$)
>
> (d) If $A$ is well-orderable, then $h(A)=h^*(A)$.
>
> (e) $h^*(A)$ exists for all $A$.

Questions:

1. I guess the authors meant to define $h^{*}(A)$ as the least ***nonzero*** ordinal $\alpha$ such that there exists no function with domain $A$ and range $\alpha$?
2. I don't see how to show (a) without using a constructive definition of $h^{*}(A)$ (as in [Hartogs's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number)):

Let $\beta=\{\alpha:\alpha \text{ is an ordinal isomorphic to some well-ordered partition of } A\}$. The set $\beta$ exists by the replacement axiom. Moreover, $\beta$ is precisely the set of ordinals $\alpha$ such that there exists a function with domain $A$ and range $\alpha$.
Then $h^{*}(A):=\beta\cup\{0\}$ is the least nonzero ordinal $\alpha$ such that there exists no function with domain $A$ and range $\alpha$.

It seems we have to answer (e) before (a)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1, yes that's correct, they should have stipulated $\alpha\ne 0.$

For 2, we can just redefine a surjection $g: A\to \alpha$ as $h(a)= g(a)$ if $g(a)<h^*(A)$ and $h(a)=0$ otherwise, and $h$ is a surjection $A\to h^*(A).$

So we only need (e) for (a) in the sense that they should have prefaced (a) with "if $h^*(A)$ exists" to make it make sense before we have proven (e).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For 2 did you invert $\alpha$ and $h^*(A)$? (by definition there is no surjection $A\to h^*(A)$). Also, is my proof of part (e) ok?

Comment: @Alphie We start with an assumption there's a surjection $A\to \alpha$ (i.e. (a) is false) and get a surjection $A\to h^*(A).$ Yes, there's no surjection $A\to h^*(A)$ by definition, so by contradiction, (a) holds.

Comment: @Alphie Your proof of (e) seems the right idea... you do seem to be implicitly using (a) in it though. (But all the same, you can just take the least ordinal not in $\beta$ as $h^*(A)$.)

Comment: Ok got it for 2. Indeed the argument to show that $\beta\cup\{0\}$ is transitive is basically the same as (a). A transitive set of ordinals is an ordinal. So the least nonzero ordinal not in  $\beta$ is $\beta\cup\{0\}$ right?

Comment: @Alphie yes, that’s right